# LINQ/MVC webservice return json file or an empty array

Tags: linq, web-services, model-view-controller

i don't know really how to formulate this but what i want is to achieve is the following, read a JSON file from a storage (direct url) but if that JSON file does not exist it should return an empty array.

this is what i got so far (and works)

```
public object GetFromFile(int Code)
{
   string uriPath = "http://mystorage.com/folder/" + Code + ".json";
   var allText = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(uriPath);
   object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
   return jsonObject;
}
```

it returns to me the requested list of codes as a array, now if the code does not exists on the storage, possible, then the webservice should just return and empty array []

desired result:

from file (works):

```
[{001},{002},{003}]
```

if file does not exist

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //The call to WebClient.DownloadString(string) will throw an exception if the 
 //uri does not exist, in your case, the json file does not exist
 var allText = null;
 object jsonObject = null;

 try
 {
     allText = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(uriPath);
     jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
 }
 catch(WebException ex)
 {
     jsonObject = new object[0];
 }
```

Comment: @EwaldBos I modified the answer. I realized that the `WebClient` method will throw a `WebException` if the `uri` is invalid, in your case, the `json` file doesn't exist. Catch the exception and set the `jsonObject` to an empty array if a `WebException` occurs else deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect that the JSON-file contains a sequence of similar items, from the look of it a sequence of integer numbers.

If you already know that the JSON-file contains this type of objects, it is better to use the overload of `DeserializeObject<int>`.

```
IEnumerable<int> ReadNumbersFromWebClient(int Code)
{
    string uriPath = "http://mystorage.com/folder/" + Code + ".json";
    var downloadedText = DownloadText(uriPath);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(allText);
}

string DownloadText(string uriPath)
{
     using (var webClient = new WebClient())
     {
         return webClient.DownloadString(uriPath);
     }
}
```

You said that you wanted to return an empty sequence if the "file does not exist". I assume that you meant: "if the web client says there is no string to download"

I looked at WebClient.DownloadString, and I couldn't find what happens if you use an uriPath that does not exist. Do you get empty string, or an exception?

```
ICollection<int> ReadNumbersFromWebClient(int Code)
{
    // in case of exception: return empty string
    try
    {
        string uriPath = "http://mystorage.com/folder/" + Code + ".json";
        var downloadedText = DownloadText(uriPath);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(allText);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) // or use specific exception
    {
        return new int[];
    }
}
```

It would be neater if you let DownloadText catch the expression. In case of exception return empty string. Experiment what happens if you try to Deserialize an empty string. It will probably be an empty `int[]`